# Haskell - Syntax error

Tags: haskell, syntax

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here? I can't figure out where the error is. I'm new to haskell, so I don't know every rule of syntax atm.

```
parseS (s:xs) | all isDigit s = (xs, Lit (read s)) 
          | s == " " = parseS xs
          | s == "-" = let (remainder, e) = parseS xs in (remainder, Sub e)
          | s == "+" = (xs'', Sum e e') where
                       (xs', e) = parseS xs 
                       (xs'', e') = parseS xs' 

          | s == "*" = (xs'', Mul e e') where     <- parse error on input on this line
                       (xs', e) = parseS xs 
                       (xs'', e') = parseS xs'
```

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. We can't run your screenshot as code.

Comment: Please post the error message, verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how Haskell sees your code:

```
parseS (s:xs)
        | all isDigit s = (xs, Lit (read s)) 
        | s == " " = parseS xs
        | s == "-" = let (remainder, e) = parseS xs in (remainder, Sub e)
        | s == "+" = (xs'', Sum e e')
    where
    (xs', e) = parseS xs 
    (xs'', e') = parseS xs' 

| s == "*" = (xs'', Mul e e')
    where
    (xs', e) = parseS xs 
    (xs'', e') = parseS xs'
```

A `where` block attaches to a declaration, which in your case is the whole `parseS` definition.

The next line starting with `|` is seen as the start of a new declaration, which is invalid because you can't start a declaration with `|`.

The easiest fix is to stop using `where` for local bindings and use `let` instead, like this:

```
          | s == "+" =
              let
                  (xs', e) = parseS xs 
                  (xs'', e') = parseS xs' 
              in
              (xs'', Sum e e')

          | s == "*" =
              let
                  (xs', e) = parseS xs 
                  (xs'', e') = parseS xs'
              in
              (xs'', Mul e e')
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the first `where` clause is taken as the end of the definition for `parseS (s:xs)`.  You're trying to add another guarded case afterwards, but the parser doesn't see it as attached to the same definition.

There's several ways you could fix this.

You *could* fix this by using a `let ... in` instead for `s == "+"`

```
      | s == "+" = let (xs', e) = parseS xs
                       (xs'', e') = parseS xs
                   in (xs'', Sum e e')
      | s == "*" = (xs'', Mul e e') where
                       (xs', e) = parseS xs 
                       (xs'', e') = parseS xs'
```

But there's an easier way to do it - just drop that `where` clause.

```
      | s == "+" = (xs'', Sum e e')
      | s == "*" = (xs'', Mul e e') where
                       (xs', e) = parseS xs 
                       (xs'', e') = parseS xs'
```

The variables defined in a `where` clause are in scope for the entirety of a definition (for all guard cases), so your definition of `xs''` can be reused for both cases.